# Comparar dos ficheros en Python

Tags: python

os pongo un poco en contexto; tenemos dos ficheros de texto:
-El primero contiene varias columnas de separadas por ',', se le pasa como parámetro al script. (file1)
-En el segundo tenemos estas mismas lineas sin la ultima columna, y es creado en el propio script. (salida)

Mi idea es recorrer los dos y exportar en un tercer fichero (salida1) las lineas del primer archivo, que se corresponden con la suya correspondiente del segundo fichero.

Esto lo hago por que en el segundo fichero además de no tener la segunda columna tampoco tenemos las filas que puedan haber repetidas del primer fichero.

He intentado desarrollar esta manera de comparar los ficheros pero a la hora de añadir la ultima columna de nuevo, me añade todas hasta de las lineas que no están en el fichero 2, ya que se supone que solo debería añadir las lineas del primero que esten en este segundo fichero junto a sus respectivas columnas.

Adjunto un trozo del código que he usado para hacer esta funcionalidad.

```
    file1 = open(sys.argv[1],'r')

    salida = open("salida.txt","r")

    i = 0
    lineas = file1.readlines()

    for linea in lineas:
        for l in salida:
            if l.find(line):
                if i == 0:
                    salida1.write(l.rstrip() + "X_CUOTA;fecha_carga" + '\n')
                    i = 1
                    break
                salida1.write(l.rstrip() + linea.join(linea.split(";")[5:-1]) + ';\n')
            else:
                print("NO ENTRA")

            break
```

Creo que puede ser por como comparo las lineas de los archivos o como recorro los archivos.

```
Archivo 1.
id,protocolo,cuota,id2
11,RJ45,12,3
34,RY19,34,7
34,RY19,34,2
55,RJ45,12,3

Archivo 2. 
id,protocolo,cuota
11,RJ45,12
55,RJ45,12

Salida.
id, protocolo,cuota,id2
11,RJ45,12,3
55,RJ45,12,7
```

Como se ve el archivo de salida y el archivo 2 no contiene la segunda linea ya que se repite la misma linea, sin tener en cuenta la ultima columna. La salida sería las lineas comunes a ambos archivos, pero como he dicho el problema está en que al generar el de salida y comparar ambos yo obtengo una salida a la cual la columna que se asocia sigue el orden del archivo de entrada, ya que como id2 muestra 7 en vez de 3 como debería de ser según el archivo 1.

El objetivo inicial del programa que desarrollo es que me pasan el archivo 1 con miles de lineas con el formato presentado y se quieren eliminar de ese archivo todas las lineas iguales sin tener en cuenta el id2, es decir, la última columna.

El archivo 2 lo uso como auxiliar para guardar el archivo 1 sin duplicados comparando solo con las columnas necesarias. No se si habría otra forma mejor de hacer esto.

Comment: Pon una muestra de los datos del archivo_1, del archivo_2 y de cómo debería quedar la salida.

Answer (score 0):

Como el formato de entrada de los archivos son un CSV, pueden ser leídos de esa manera.

Ahora se recorre cada elemento de `dataf1`, como la última columna depende del orden de `dataf1` y no de la coincidencia con `dataf2`, entonces hay que acumular ese dato en una variable, yo le llamo `index` y otra variable `i` que indica cual es será el siguiente elemento de esa última columna.

Ahora toca simplemente comparar si todos los elementos de `dataf2` están en las sublistas de `dataf1`. Si es así `match = item` y se reemplaza el último elemento por el correspondiente `index[i]`

```
import csv

def read_csv(nfile, delimiter=','):
    data = []
    with open(nfile, newline='') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=delimiter)
        for line in reader:
            data.append(line)
    return data

dataf1 = read_csv('archivo1.txt')
dataf2 = read_csv('archivo2.txt')
index = []
i = 0
result = []
for item in dataf1:
    index.append(item[-1])
    for sublist in dataf2:
        if all(x in item for x in sublist):
            match = item
            match[-1] = index[i]
            result.append(match)
            i += 1
print(result)
```

La salida de este código, con los datos de entrada sería:

```
[['id', 'protocolo', 'cuota', 'id2'], ['11', 'RJ45', '12', '3'], ['55', 'RJ45', '12', '7']]
```

La variable `result` es una lista con los datos resultantes, que si quieres puedes escribir a un archivo con las rutinas correspondientes.